# iOS 14.5 or 14.6 onwards accessing UIApplication.shared.open or UIApplication.shared.openURL in Share Extension gives "APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY"

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Prior to iOS 14.5 or 14.6, we could launch the main app from a share extension by setting `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to `NO` and using:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(urlToOpen, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlToOpen)
}
```

But iOS 14.5 or 14.6 onwards, we get this error when building:

```
Application extensions and any libraries they link to must be built with the `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY` build setting set to YES.
```

Is there a way to launch the main app from share sheet extension in iOS 14.5/14.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a solution which lets you launch the main app while keeping `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to `YES`.

Set the `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to `YES` as Apple wants you to.

Then use this in the Extension:

```
let sharedSelector = NSSelectorFromString("sharedApplication")
let openSelector = NSSelectorFromString("openURL:")

if let urlToOpen = URL(string: "YOURAPPURLSCHEME://whatever_you_need_to_pass"), UIApplication.responds(to: sharedSelector), let shared = UIApplication.perform(sharedSelector)?.takeRetainedValue() as? UIApplication, shared.responds(to: openSelector) {

    shared.perform(openSelector, with: urlToOpen)

}

//do the rest of extension completion stuff....
self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
```